# Paying automatically from PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to know if the following scenario can be developed.

I have a website where the mode of payment is pay-by-usage. So when the customer exceeds a particular amount, I need to charge his PayPal account automatically. Is this possible in the PayPal API?

Comment: I think this use case https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/use-cases/uc_subscriptions-subscription-payments-usage/ meets your needs exactly eeven has a set up guide

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal Adaptive payment and there is an option to charge user account automatically. It is called [PayPal Pre Approval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) payment.

In the first phase the user has to authorize your app to perform payment onbehalf of user. During this authorization step, you will get and authorize pre approval key. Later you could automatically charge user PayPal account using this key.